# How to get a character delimited substring?

Tags: c, string

Some lines of a text file contain a line which starts with an open square bracket, has a variable number of characters followed by a close square bracket and then some further text

For example:

```
 [ABC]  why is the sky green?  
 [DEFG]  Ou sont les Niegedens d'antan?  
 [I can't code C]  (... obviously)
```

How do I get the text between the square brackets?  (I want to `printf` it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would probably be a scanset conversion:

```
char line[256];

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
    char string[256];

    sscanf(line, "[%255[^]]", string);
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

Comment: +1 and the answer. Althoug I suspect that you meant   sscanf(line, "[%255[^]]", string);

Answer (score 1):

Read line by line, compare the first character against `[`, and use `strchr` to locate the closing square brackets `]`.

For arbitrary long line, you can use `fgets` to read into temporary buffer, and check for the line terminator to avoid accidentally capturing text in bracket that is in the middle of the line. To print out, you may want to print as you go (and stop when going to next line or encounter `]`), or buffer it up in your own implementation of string builder.